# Show and image when button selected

Tags: javascript, html

Having so much trouble with something I feel like should be easy. I am supposed to have a page with three buttons. Labeled 1, 2, and 3. When you click one you see an image. Different image for each button.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated. I am pretty new to this and have been at this simple task for hours. Thanks!

```js
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang = "en"> 
<head> <title> Assignment 6.5.html </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" /> 
<head>
<!-- Script for the event handler -->

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick= "showImage();" type="button" value='1' id='cat'> 1 </button>
    <button onclick= "showImage();" type="button" value='2' id='dog'> 2 </button>
    <button onclick= "showImage();" type="button" value='1' id='werewolf'> 3 </button>
    
    <img src="data:," alt>

    <script>

            function showImage(event)
            {
                if (document.getElementById("cat").src == "Cat1.jpg") 
                {   
                 if (document.getElementById("dog").src == "dog2.jpg")
                {                    
                if (document.getElementById("werewolf").src == "werewolf3.jpg")
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html> <html lang = "en"> 
<head> <title> Assignment 6.5.html </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" /> 
<head>
<!-- Script for the event handler -->

<head>
<body>
    <button onclick= "showImage();" type="button" value='1' id='cat'> 1 </button>
    <button onclick= "showImage();" type="button" value='2' id='dog'> 2 </button>
    <button onclick= "showImage();" type="button" value='1' id='werewolf'> 3 </button>

     
<p>
    <script>

            function showImage()
            {
                if (document.getElementById("cat").src == "Cat1.jpg") 
                {   
                 if (document.getElementById("dog").scr == "dog2.jpg")
                {                    
                if (document.getElementById("werewolf").scr == "werewolf3.jpg")
            }
            
        </script>
</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You wrote ".scr", it should be ".src". And replace "==" with "=".

Comment: "src" means "source", it's the URl of the image. The "==" checks for equality of the two sides, while the "=" sets the value of the variable on the left side to the one on the right.

Comment: Also the if's are wrong.

Comment: I fixed up the = and .src . Can you help me out with the if statement? Is that why nothing happens on button click?

Comment: you want to change the content of the buttons or show an image on a different place?

Comment: When I click it I just want a picture to show up not the content of the button to change.

Comment: To clarify all buttons remain on the page but the image is there. Then if I select a different button a different image pops up.

Comment: You need to create an <img> element with empty src. The showImage should be called with the event parameter: "showImage(event);" Then in the function showImage(event) you should test if the event.target equals (==) to the cat, the dog or the werewolf button, and set the img element's src accordingly.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE.html> should be <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: The <head> tag should be closed properly using </head>

Comment: Do I put the <img> element in the script portion or up in the HTML?

Comment: The <script> tag should NOT be wrapped in <p>...</p>

Comment: No, the <img> tag is part of the HTML, so it must be outside the <script> tag

Comment: Still not functioning. Is there a way for me to post the updates in code I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should get the HTML elements as JavaScript variables. You can use getElementById for this (although querySelector is more flexible). You should pass the event object to showImage and check event.target to determine which button was clicked. Depending on the button, you can set the src of the image element, like this:

```
<button onclick= "showImage(event);" id="cat">1</button>
<button onclick= "showImage(event);" id="dog">2</button>
<button onclick= "showImage(event);" id="werewolf">3</button>
<img id="animal" />
<script>
  catButton = document.getElementById("cat");
  dogButton = document.getElementById("dog");
  werewolfButton = document.getElementById("werewolf");
  img = document.getElementById("animal");

  function showImage(event) {
    if (event.target == catButton) {
      img.src = "cat.jpg"
    } if (event.target == dogButton) {
      img.src = "dog.jpg"
    } if (event.target == werewolfButton) {
      img.src = "werewolf.jpg"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, kol! That worked. I think I need to review how, but seriously thank you. I have been hitting my head against the wall for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Think out the requirement a little further.
I assume you want to display the image on it's own rather than inside each respective button. The [`src` attribute of `button`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_src) replaces the button with the image. You need actually need a dedicated area to display the image. You also should probably decide if you want to load all the images up front and then show the relevant one and hide the others on each click or simply load the relevant image in the designated area on-the fly.
The below code will load the relevant image on-the-fly when the button is clicked. If the images are different sizes you would need to adjust the height and width of 'display-area' on each click.

HTML

```
<img id="display-area" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" width="500" height="500"/>
<button id='cat' onclick="showImage(this);"> 1 </button>
<button id='dog' onclick="showImage(this);"> 2 </button>
<button id='werewolf' onclick="showImage(this);"> 3 </button>
```

JavaScript

```
function showImage(button) {
  let urls = {
    cat: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=animal-pet-cute-kitten-45201.jpg&fm=jpg',
    dog: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518155317743-a8ff43ea6a5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80',
    werewolf: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Werwolf.png'
  };
  let img = document.getElementById('display-area');
  img.src = urls[button.id]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some faulty tags so I fixed that as well. Commented that in the code.

You can send in parameters in your function call, which contains the link to the image - either relative or absolute paths. In my example, I got absolute paths.

```css
#image {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en"> 
<head> <title> Assignment 6.5.html </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" /> 
<!-- <head> you should only have one head -->

<!-- <head> Missing slash --> 
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="showImage('https://picsum.photos/200/300')" type="button"> 1 </button>
        <button onclick="showImage('https://picsum.photos/300/100')" type="button"> 2 </button>
        <button onclick="showImage('https://picsum.photos/50/50')" type="button"> 3 </button>
    </div>

    <img src="" id="image"> <!-- added an image tag -->
     
</body>


<script>

    function showImage(imageSrc)
    {
      let imageElement = document.getElementById("image");

      if (imageElement) { // check that the image exists
        imageElement.src = imageSrc;
      }
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[here is life answer](https://codepen.io/agakesik/pen/ExPyZmJ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Assignment 6.5.html </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" /> 
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      <button onclick= "showImage(this.id)" id="cat"> 1 </button>
      <button onclick= "showImage(this.id);" id='dog'> 2 </button>
      <button onclick= "showImage(this.id);" id='werewolf'> 3 </button>
    </div>
    <img id="myImg" src="">

    <script>
    function showImage(object) {
      let src = ""
      if (object == "cat") {
        src = "path/to/img"
      } else if (object == "dog") {
        src = "path/to/img"
      } else if (object == "werewolf") {
        src = "path/to/img"
      }
      document.getElementById("myImg").src = src;
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```